# How can I add action menu in usermenu odoo15

Tags: javascript, menu, odoo, odoo-15

In odoo 15, how can I add new action menu in user menu? In other odoo versions (13 and 14), it was possible by inheriting from `UserMenu.Actions`.

In odoo 15, I tried the following code but it is not working.

Thanks for any suggestion

```html
/** @odoo-module **/

import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";
import { preferencesItem } from "@web/webclient/user_menu/user_menu_items";

export function UserLog(env) {
    return Object.assign(
        {},
        preferencesItem(env),
        {
            type: "item",
            id: "log",
            description: env._t("UserRecent Log"),
            callback: async function () {
                const actionDescription = await env.services.orm.call("user.recent.log", "action_get");
                actionDescription.res_id = env.services.user.userId;
                env.services.action.doAction(actionDescription);
            },
            sequence: 70,
        }
    );
}

registry.category("user_menuitems").add('profile', UserLog, { force: true })
```

This is my model code.

```html
class UserRecentLog(models.Model):
    _name = 'user.recent.log'
    _order = "last_visited_on desc"

    
    @api.model
    def action_get(self):
        return self.env['ir.actions.act_window']._for_xml_id('user_recent_log.action_user_activity')
```

This is my xml view.

```html
    <!-- actions opening views on models -->    
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_user_activity">
        <field name="name">User Recent Log(s)</field>
        <field name="res_model">user.recent.log</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="user_activity_view_tree"/>
    </record>
```

Comment: What is the "(an)other odoo version"?

Comment: @CZoellner odoo 13 and 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change anything, your code should work. You can check the user preferences menu item in [web](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/webclient/user_menu/user_menu_items.js#L61) module (similar to your menu item).

```
export function preferencesItem(env) {
    return {
        type: "item",
        id: "settings",
        description: env._t("Preferences"),
        callback: async function () {
            const actionDescription = await env.services.orm.call("res.users", "action_get");
            actionDescription.res_id = env.services.user.userId;
            env.services.action.doAction(actionDescription);
        },
        sequence: 50,
    };
}

registry
    .category("user_menuitems")
    .add("profile", preferencesItem)
```

There is another implementation in [hr](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/hr/static/src/js/user_menu.js#L3) module:

```
import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";
import { preferencesItem } from "@web/webclient/user_menu/user_menu_items";

export function hrPreferencesItem(env)  {
    return Object.assign(
        {}, 
        preferencesItem(env),
        {
            description: env._t('My Profile'),
        }
    );
}

registry.category("user_menuitems").add('profile', hrPreferencesItem, { force: true })
```

So you can rewrite your code above as following:

```
import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";
import { preferencesItem } from "@web/webclient/user_menu/user_menu_items";

export function UserLog(env) {
    return Object.assign(
        {},
        preferencesItem(env),
        {
            type: "item",
            id: "log",
            description: env._t("Log"),
            callback: async function () {
                const actionDescription = await env.services.orm.call("res.users.log", "action_user_activity");
                env.services.action.doAction(actionDescription);
            },
            sequence: 70,
        }
    );
}

registry.category("user_menuitems").add('profile', UserLog, { force: true })
```

### Edit:

The `tree` view mode is ignored when executing the window action.

The [_executeActWindowAction](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/webclient/actions/action_service.js#L784) will check for the `tree` view type in the views registry to construct the `views` object and unfortunately, the tree view mode was not added to that [registry](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/views/view_registry.js#L34).

To show the tree view, you can add `[false, 'list']` to the views list and specify the view type (`list`) in the [doAction](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/webclient/actions/action_service.js#L1099) options:

```
actionDescription.views.push([actionDescription.view_id[0], 'list'])
env.services.action.doAction(actionDescription, {viewType: 'list'});
```

Or update the views list and change `tree` to `list`:

```
actionDescription.views[0][1] = 'list';
```

Of course , you can do the same in the `action_get` method:

```
action = self.env['ir.actions.act_window']._for_xml_id('user_recent_log.action_user_activity')
action['views'][0] = action['view_id'][0], 'list'
return action
```

Comment: It's not working.When I use it, my screen is not displayed.The screen changed to white screen.

Comment: I have tested the code and the menu item is added to the profile, but I have not tested the callback function

Comment: Is there any error in the console log?

Comment: No error message in console.I use res.users.log is model name and action_user_activity is ir.actions.act_window name. My odoo app page change to white screen

Comment: Check my edit, I don't think the error is caused by the menu item

Comment: Yes Kenly, now displayed in user menu .But when I click, always display form view.I want to show tree view.Check my edit.

Comment: The `tree` mode is ignored, check my edit